# Flying Tree Sharks! :P

Tags: riddle, haiku

> The flying tree sharks
> Are out, on the hunt for prey.
> In the dead of night.
>
> When day awakens,
> The flying tree sharks die out.
> They'll be back at dusk.

What is a flying tree shark?

Hint:

> It's not aquatic.

Comment: \**whispers*\* Thaaank youuuuuu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the flying tree sharks are

> Bats

Explanation:

```
The flying tree sharks  
Are out, on the hunt for prey.  
At the dead of night.
```

> Bats are flying animals that hunt for their prey at night and often roost in trees (as well as hollow trees and caves). They are likened to sharks because of their predatory nature.

```
When day awakens,
The flying tree sharks die out.
They'll be back at dusk.
```

> They go to sleep during the day, usually hiding away so you can't see them. They come back out as it starts to get dark again.

Comment: @manshu I didn't think it needed an explanation, but I've edited one in especially for you. :)

Comment: I don't really know how it fits the shark thing.

Comment: @manshu added more detail for you.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer, but it fits so perfectly. So, I'll give it to you. You did it! YAY!!!

Comment: @You, if this isn't the correct answer what is?

Answer (score 5):

The flying tree sharks are:

> Owls

The flying tree sharks
Are out, on the hunt for prey.
At the dead of night.

> Owls hunt for prey at night.

When day awakens,
The flying tree sharks die out.
They'll be back at dusk.

> Owls usually sleep in the day.

The "flying tree shark" is that because:

> Owls fly, live in trees, and are predators (like sharks).

Comment: This could technically apply to any number of nocturnal tree dwelling predators